Angular 18 Library & Showcase - ng test doesn't find Spec files
tldr; Trying to determine why running ng test library is returning Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS.
I have an Angular Workspace setup with two projects:

Workspace

Projects

Library
Showcase





The Library project and Showcase projects are separate Angular applications with a singular angular.json file.
The Library Project, is made up of reusable components to be distributed across different Angular applications, and is structured as (using ButtonComponent as an example):

button

src

button.component.html
button.component.spec.ts
button.component.ts


index.ts
ng-package.json
public-api.ts



To run Unit Tests on the Library project, I call ng test library (where library is the Project name of the Library application); however, no tests are found.
I'm not positive, but I think the issue is with my tsconfig.spec.json file:
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../out-tsc/spec",
        "types": ["jasmine"]
    },
    "include": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.d.ts"]
}

Even though it's specified to include all *.spec.ts files, it doesn't seem to be finding them. This file is at the path /projects/library/tsconfig.spec.json.
My tsconfig.json file is at the root.
Within my angular.json file, this is how test is configured for the library project:
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
    "tsConfig": "projects/library/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
    "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
    "codeCoverage": true
  }
}

I've tried everything I know and everything looks like it's pointing to the proper things. I even tried including button/src/*.spec.ts in tsconfig.spec.json and it still didn't find the at test.
Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing here?
TIA!

in your tsconfig.json, did you check if you added a "exclude": property by adding any spec files in that value of that property? Also please check karma.conf.js exclude files property.

@SrikarPhaniKumarM Just checked tsconfig.json and karma.conf.js. Both match what I use in other applications and neither have an excludes property set. tsconfig.lib.json does have exclude and **/*.spec.ts, but the Specs wouldn't be looking at that.
